# Intellij IDEA 11.0.2 fails to resolve dependencies on Grails 2.0.0

Tags: grails, groovy, intellij-idea

This is my first question here and I hope that it's not already been asked. 
Problem:

Every time I create a new app using Intellij IDEA 11.0.2 build 111.277 with the new Grails 2.0.0 I get the following stack trace:

```
| Loading Grails 2.0.0
| Configuring classpath
:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.grails.plugins#tomcat;1.3.7
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#tomcat;1.3.7!tomcat.zip:
      /home/Mircea/IdeaProjects/lib/tomcat-1.3.7.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/lib/org.grails.plugins/tomcat/ivy-1.3.7.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#tomcat;1.3.7!tomcat.zip:
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/lib/org.grails.plugins/tomcat/jars/tomcat-1.3.7.zip
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/lib/org.grails.plugins/tomcat/bundles/tomcat-1.3.7.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/src/libs/tomcat-1.3.7.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#tomcat;1.3.7!tomcat.zip:
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/src/libs/tomcat-1.3.7.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/dist/tomcat-1.3.7.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#tomcat;1.3.7!tomcat.zip:
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/dist/tomcat-1.3.7.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/Mircea/.grails/2.0.0/cached-installed-plugins/tomcat-1.3.7.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#tomcat;1.3.7!tomcat.zip:
      /home/Mircea/.grails/2.0.0/cached-installed-plugins/tomcat-1.3.7.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#tomcat;1.3.7!tomcat.zip:
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/plugins/tomcat-1.3.7.zip
        module not found: org.grails.plugins#hibernate;1.3.7
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#hibernate;1.3.7!hibernate.zip:
      /home/Mircea/IdeaProjects/lib/hibernate-1.3.7.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/lib/org.grails.plugins/hibernate/ivy-1.3.7.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#hibernate;1.3.7!hibernate.zip:
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/lib/org.grails.plugins/hibernate/jars/hibernate-1.3.7.zip
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/lib/org.grails.plugins/hibernate/bundles/hibernate-1.3.7.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/src/libs/hibernate-1.3.7.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#hibernate;1.3.7!hibernate.zip:
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/src/libs/hibernate-1.3.7.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/dist/hibernate-1.3.7.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#hibernate;1.3.7!hibernate.zip:
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/dist/hibernate-1.3.7.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/Mircea/.grails/2.0.0/cached-installed-plugins/hibernate-1.3.7.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#hibernate;1.3.7!hibernate.zip:
      /home/Mircea/.grails/2.0.0/cached-installed-plugins/hibernate-1.3.7.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#hibernate;1.3.7!hibernate.zip:
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/plugins/hibernate-1.3.7.zip
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        :: org.grails.plugins#tomcat;1.3.7: not found
        :: org.grails.plugins#hibernate;1.3.7: not found
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        module not found: org.grails.plugins#tomcat;1.3.7
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#tomcat;1.3.7!tomcat.zip:
      /home/Mircea/IdeaProjects/lib/tomcat-1.3.7.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/lib/org.grails.plugins/tomcat/ivy-1.3.7.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#tomcat;1.3.7!tomcat.zip:
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/lib/org.grails.plugins/tomcat/jars/tomcat-1.3.7.zip
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/lib/org.grails.plugins/tomcat/bundles/tomcat-1.3.7.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/src/libs/tomcat-1.3.7.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#tomcat;1.3.7!tomcat.zip:
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/src/libs/tomcat-1.3.7.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/dist/tomcat-1.3.7.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#tomcat;1.3.7!tomcat.zip:
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/dist/tomcat-1.3.7.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/Mircea/.grails/2.0.0/cached-installed-plugins/tomcat-1.3.7.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#tomcat;1.3.7!tomcat.zip:
      /home/Mircea/.grails/2.0.0/cached-installed-plugins/tomcat-1.3.7.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#tomcat;1.3.7!tomcat.zip:
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/plugins/tomcat-1.3.7.zip
        module not found: org.grails.plugins#hibernate;1.3.7
    ==== grailsPlugins: tried
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#hibernate;1.3.7!hibernate.zip:
      /home/Mircea/IdeaProjects/lib/hibernate-1.3.7.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/lib/org.grails.plugins/hibernate/ivy-1.3.7.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#hibernate;1.3.7!hibernate.zip:
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/lib/org.grails.plugins/hibernate/jars/hibernate-1.3.7.zip
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/lib/org.grails.plugins/hibernate/bundles/hibernate-1.3.7.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/src/libs/hibernate-1.3.7.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#hibernate;1.3.7!hibernate.zip:
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/src/libs/hibernate-1.3.7.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/dist/hibernate-1.3.7.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#hibernate;1.3.7!hibernate.zip:
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/dist/hibernate-1.3.7.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      /home/Mircea/.grails/2.0.0/cached-installed-plugins/hibernate-1.3.7.xml
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#hibernate;1.3.7!hibernate.zip:
      /home/Mircea/.grails/2.0.0/cached-installed-plugins/hibernate-1.3.7.zip
    ==== grailsHome: tried
      -- artifact org.grails.plugins#hibernate;1.3.7!hibernate.zip:
      /home/Mircea/SDKs/grails-2.0.0/plugins/hibernate-1.3.7.zip
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        :: org.grails.plugins#tomcat;1.3.7: not found
        :: org.grails.plugins#hibernate;1.3.7: not found
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.grails.plugins:tomcat:1.3.7
- org.grails.plugins:hibernate:1.3.7
```

Any thoughts? I already searched for solution, but didn't quite find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Check the `BuildConfig.groovy` for hardcoded version numbers on the plugins.  It should be referencing `$grailsVersion`:

```
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    . . .
    plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
        . . .
    }
    . . .
}
```

Check the `application.properties` to make sure it's correct:

```
app.grails.version=2.0.0
plugins.hibernate=2.0.0
plugins.tomcat=2.0.0
```

Also check the IDEA Grails library version in Project Settings -> Global Libraries.

---

I just patched to 11.0.2 and created a new Grails 2.0.0 project successfully.

It's possible your Grails 2.0.0 installation is corrupt.  Try a clean installation of Grails:

1. Delete the Grails 2.0.0 global library from IDEA.
2. Install Grails 2.0.0 into a new directory.
3. Create a new Grails project in IDEA and use the "Create ..." button to set up the new installation.

Comment: They are like that in the BuildConfig.groovy. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Project Settings -> Global Libraries -> Grails library of version 2.0.0

Comment: plugins {
        runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
        runtime ":jquery:1.7.1"
        runtime ":resources:1.1.5"

        build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"
    } `code`

Comment: I get: $ grails clean
| Configuring classpath
| Error /home/.../IdeaProjects/TestG2 does not appear to be part of a Grails application.
| Error The following commands are supported outside of a project:
And if I run grails create-app I get the same error involving those two dependencies.

Comment: I still get | Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- org.grails.plugins:tomcat:1.3.7
- org.grails.plugins:hibernate:1.3.7 after I've install it in a different folder.

Comment: @mdstaicu Have you tried running `grails create-app` directly from the cli?

Comment: Yes, of course. First thing. The difference is that from the CLI it doesn't create the folder of the project, but in IDEA, it creates it, well, partially, with few files in it.

Comment: @mdstaicu Updated to check `application.properties`

Comment: Like I said, from CLI, it doesn't create the structure at all, but from IDEA it creates the most basic java project, only with src, the .idea and projectName.iml. There is no application.properties.